# Exception thrown when Request.Form["blah"] is called on a checkbox form value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Very strange error, i have a field on an MVC View:

```
<%: Html.CheckBox("Reportable", ViewData["Reportable"])%>
```

Im guessing this is bad practice, but i need a boolean value, and am trying to get it from the FormCollection on postback by doing:

```
wasteStreamReciever.ERCBReportable = bool.Parse(Request.Form["Reportable"]);
```

Am i doing it wrong? Is there a better way?

## edit

I have also tried to no avail:

```
bool bchk = false;
bool.TryParse(Request.Form["Reportable"], out bchk);
```

## edit2

The exception being thrown is:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException
```

Comment: What exception is being thrown?

Comment: check edit #2, from what i can tell its pretty common, but there are alot of factors that could cause it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTML checkbox should only pass its value when checked.  If you only need to know whether the 'Reportable' box was checked, you don't need to parse the value at all; you just need to see whether there is a value.

Comment: Even if i take the request.form out, and i check the check box and post back, i still get the exception

Comment: I assume there are other fields in your form as well.  Do any of them (including your checkbox) have values that contain HTML?

Comment: Ok, i fixed that wierd issue. Onto checking if there is a value in the reportable box. Do i compare request.form["Reportable"] to null?

Comment: AFAIK that should be enough.  If the box isn't checked, `Request.Form["Reportable"]` should be null.  This all assumes, of course, that you have one "Reportable" box on the page, and no other elements (like textboxes and textareas) with the same name.